# How to get list items from a folder in custom list using rest API?

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2013

I am working with Office 365. I have used REST API for different types of operations. I can easily find list items in a folder in document library because they are files. I want the list items in a folder in custom list. For this I am not able to find any REST API. Can you please provide me any REST API which will be able to retrieve list items from folder in custom list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. Following is the way

```
var camlQuery = {
    'query': {
        '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' },
        'ViewXml': '<View><Query/></View>',
        'FolderServerRelativeUrl': '/sites/EdvelopTest3/Lists/QuestionsList/test/test1'
    }
};

var url = OEPContext.appWebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getByTitle('OEPLMSQuestions')/getitems?$select=ID,Title&@target='" + OEPContext.hostWebUrl + "'";
jQuery.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(camlQuery),
    success: function (data) {             
        var result = "success";
    },
    error: function (data, msg) {
        var result = "Fail";
    }
});
```